# Automatically propagate types in IDA pro when variables are assigned?

Tags: ida, idapython

Let's say I have this code in the decompiler of IDA pro:

```
var1 = var2;
```

And assume the type of `var1` is `X` (for example `X` could be char array with size 5). Is there anyway that I can tell IDA that whenever you see such assignments, change the type of `var2` to `X` as well?

Considering that `var1` is type `X`, then obviously `var2` should be type `X` as well, but right now I have to manually change the type every time… The problem is this is happening inside a large function thousands of times and I can't manually change every time, I need to somehow force IDA to do it. But how?

Comment: If var1 is never re-assigned deeper in the function (meaning that it is just an exact copy of var2), you can try the "=" shortcut to merge the two variables. I know this is not exactely what you've asked, but it may same you some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HexRaysPyTools](https://github.com/igogo-x86/HexRaysPyTools) has this feature, which it calls "recasting" (`SHIFT-L`, `SHIFT-R`). It's generally an excellent piece of software and I recommend it.